# Is there a minimum CPU requirement for a single call using G729?

Tags: amazon-ec2, asterisk

I am just trying this out on an AWS micro VM, which gives out roughly the equivalent of a 600Mhz processor. Currently call quality is poor, but I am trying to ascertain if this is due to a lack of CPU, or some other issue.

The kernel has a 1000Hz clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voip depends on a lot of factors. 600MHz is not much but I think it should be sufficient for a single call.
You could test using the same call with G711 (whithout compacting) and the CPU should be sufficient. If the call is OK, then you may have a too small cpu speed for compacting but you probably are using a softphone + headphone/mic and I think there is a good chance your quality problem to be in these.